# Get wrong name on sheet onEdit

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a sheet that is a template (KundJobbTemplate). Every time the user update a cell (F1) a copy of the template sheet (KundJobbTemplate) should be created with the name "Kund_xxxx:Jobb_xxxx".

This works fine the first time. But if not rename manually the newly created sheet "Kund_xxxx:Jobb_xxxx" and create a new sheet by updating cell F1 in template sheet (KundJobbTemplate), the new sheet will get the name "Copy of KundJobbTemplate" instead of "Copy of Kund_xxxx:Jobb_xxxx".

So how can I create a new sheet onEdit (user update a cell) and every time the copy of the template sheet "KundJobbTemplate" will get the name "Kund_xxxx:Jobb_xxxx" and if sheet already
exist give it a name "Copy of Kund_xxxx:Jobb_xxxx" etc.

This is my code:

```
function onEdit(event)
{
    var myNewSheetName = "Kund_xxxx:Jobb_xxxx";
    var changedCell= event.source.getActiveRange().getA1Notation();
    if (changedCell == 'F1') {
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('KundJobbMall').copyTo(ss);
        SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // Utilities.sleep(2000);
        sheet.setName(myNewSheetName);
        ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to name the new sheet the same as an existing sheet which is giving an error.  Try adding a random string at the end:

```
function onEdit(event)
{
  var randomString = (new Date%9e6).toString(36);
    var myNewSheetName = "Kund_xxxx:Jobb_xxxx";
    var changedCell= event.source.getActiveRange().getA1Notation();
    if (changedCell == 'A1') {
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('KundJobbMall').copyTo(ss).setName(myNewSheetName + " - " + randomString);
        ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);
        }
}
```

You can use any random string, var randomString above is just an example.

Comment: Thx, that made it :)!

Comment: used nr of sheets as unique string: `var nrOfSheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getNumSheets();
  var randomString = nrOfSheets.toString();`